# Why does this negation condition becomes true?

Tags: perl

I have below code, I got confused with (`if (!$ACTIVE{$id}) {`) condition.

```
my %ACTIVE = (
          '2' => $VAR1->{'17'},
          '12' => $VAR1->{'17'},
          '18' => $VAR1->{'15'},
          '11' => $VAR1->{'15'},
          '3' => $VAR1->{'17'},
          '5' => $VAR1->{'17'}
);

my %NAMES = (
     '3' => 'IND',
     '2' => 'UK',
     '5' => 'USA',
     '11' => 'SA',
     '12' => 'AUS',
     '18' => 'CAN'
);

my $id = 3; #Input

if ($id) {
     my $name = $NAMES{$id};
     if (!$ACTIVE{$id}) {
          print "Region \'$name\' is not active\n";
     } else {
          print "Region \'$name\' is active\n"
     }
}
```

Since `$id` is my input and according to condition value for `$ACTIVE{$id}` is `$VAR1->{'17'}` which is present in the hash.

I am thinking it should print "Region 'IND' is active", but its printing "Region 'IND' is not active". Could someone say why it is? Even though I have value for ACTIVE ID 3.

Comment: You are missing some values in the hash ref `$VAR1`. There are some clues that points to it being a boolean value. Also, `$VAR1` is the syntax used by the `Data::Dumper` module, so perhaps whoever wrote that program intended to load data dumped by `Dumper` into a file. Something like `my $VAR1 = do './settings.pl';`

Answer (score 1):

`$ACTIVE{3}` is `$VAR1->{'17'}` which is a falsy value because `$VAR1` doesn't exist.

This problem would have been highlighted if you had used `use strict; use warnings;`.

Comment: Yes, I have added `use strict; use warnings;` in the code block as well and this asked me to declare `$VAR1`. I am thinking `$VAR1->{'17'}` whole as an value for ID 3.

Comment: @vkk05 — Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve].